# Check string for first 4 or last 4 characters to match a string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I was wondering if it is possible to do this in bash with awk or sed.

I have the following sample file:

```
HISEQ:272:CB0A0ANXX:3:1112:15781:21284_1:N:0:CATCAC 0   ITR3p_deleted   84279   41  35= *   0   0   TTAAGGAGGCTTCCTTTTCTAAACGATTGGGTGAG JJJ0JIIIIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJIJJJIHJJJJ NM:i:0  AM:i:41
HISEQ:272:CB0A0ANXX:3:1115:13546:24638_1:N:0:CATCAC 16  ITR3p_deleted   84279   39  15= *   0   0   TTAAGGAGGCTTCCT BB/FFFF//FBBBBB NM:i:0  AM:i:39
HISEQ:272:CB0A0ANXX:3:1114:4292:31240_1:N:0:CATCAC  16  ITR3p_deleted   83635   45  179=    *   0   0   AGATCCTATTAGATACATAGATCCTCGTCGCGATATCGCATTTTCTAACGTGATGGATATATTAA   BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJIJIJJIJJJJJJJJ8JJJJJFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFF<FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFB<<FB<//<< NM:i:0  AM:i:45
HISEQ:272:CB0A0ANXX:3:2104:14047:17929_1:N:0:CATCAC 16  ITR3p_deleted   84274   33  5X120=  *   0   0   TAAGGTTAAGGAGGCTTCCTTTTCTAATAATGATATGTATCAATCGGTGTGTAGAAAGTGTTACATCGACTCATAATATTATATTT  F7/FFFFBF77///F/7FF/<</</FBF</<<F</B//<//FFFFFFB/F/FBFBF//</F/F</F<<FBBFFFFFFFFFFFF<FFFBFFFFBFF<F<FFFB/F/FBFFFFFFFFFFBFB/</<<   NM:i:5  AM:i:33
```

And I want to check the string of the 10th column. If it starts with TTAA as in the first two examples, I want to extract those records into file-1. If it ends in TTAA such as in the third example, I would like to extract this into file-2. The fourth record would get ignored.

Can't seem to find string matches with awk.

Thanks.

Comment: please add the code you tried with awk... for matching particular column, you can use `$10 ~ /^TTAA/` or `$10 ~ /TTAA$/` and so on

Comment: I see lots of ACTG's here. Are you doing something with DNA sequencing here?

Comment: absolutely, this is a sam file format. What I am trying to do is identify reads that have mapped that start or end with TTAA. I then want to count amount of reads per TTAA site in the genome. Sometimes TTAA happens in the middle, and I do not want to count those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try, following.

```
awk '$10 ~ /^TTAA/{print > "file-1";next} $10 ~ /TTAA$/{print > "file-2"}'  Input_file
```

Comment: I like yours better than mine. It takes about 1/10th the time. If only I knew more about awk.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
cat samplefile.txt | while read line; do
  if [[ $(echo "$line" | awk '{print $10}' | grep '^TTAA')  ]]; then
    echo "$line" >> file-1.txt
  fi
  if [[ $(echo "$line" | awk '{print $10}' | grep 'TTAA$') ]]; then
    echo "$line" >> file-2.txt
  fi     
done
```

Comment: This is a very nice way of grep-ing only a certain column

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rne '/^(\S+\s+){9}TTAA/w file1' -e '/^(\S+\s+){9}\S+TTAA\>/w file2' file
```

Invoke seds grep-like nature and write to separate files depending on the regexp.

N.B. a single line may be written to both output files if the regexp is matched.